# Alphabetical Order not Working for References in MDPI Template for Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, chicago-style, mdpi

I am working with the MDPI Template for Overleaf. I have not added any supplementary package.
I have created a .bib file for my references. The entries of the .bib file get retrieved in the .tex but once placed in the References section, they are placed by order of appearance in the text, and not by alphabetical order.
At the same time, following every re-compilation, the References section seems unresponsive to any attempt to change the style.
Might somebody help?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider that I resolved the problem as soon as I selected in the preamble the specific mdpi journal for my work. After the journal selection, the references automatically aligned.